# Nodejs app in Azure app service always returns HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to learn azure app services deploying a very basic nodejs "hello world" applicatio. I deploy successfully the app from Azure Devops server release pipeline, I can see the app in azure portal in started state but when I try to access it I get

> This sieracnodejasdemo.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found HTTP
> ERROR 404.
> whereas app is up and running

[image]

Here is the basic index.js

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, res) {


    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    var url = request.url;

    if (url === '/about') {
        res.write(' Welcome to about us page');
        res.end();
    } else if (url === '/contact') {
        res.write(' Welcome to contact us page');
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.write('Hello World!');
        res.end();
    }
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
console.log(port);
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server running at http://%d", port);
```

It seems to me that it is a problem of PORT, so 1st question should I add a firewall rule for the port? I even replaced
process.env.PORT
by 80 but id did not help, always the same error. I tried to change the node version to ~10 or 18 in settings but did not help neither. So what am I missing to make it respond correctly? Knowing that when I run it on my local machine it works fine
Thanks for your help

Comment: Why you need a firewall? Is the website going to be public or just a private domain? In that case you can set up a firewall and whitelist IP addresses that may connect with that domain / server otherwise you don't actually need one.

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to repro the same in my environment and am able to deploy the nodeJS application successfully after following the below steps**.

Step 1: Created a Sample nodeJS application in VS code and pushed it to Azure Repos.

Step 2: Create build steps as below. [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Step 3: Run the pipeline and verify the artefact generated.

Step 4: Create an Azure App service with Runtime ‘**Node 18 LTS’** and Operating system **Linux**

Step5: Create a Service connection in Azure DevOps

Step 6: Create a Release pipeline as below. [image] [image] [image] [image]

Step 7: Once deployment is completed, verify the app service. [image]

Comment: Thanks Sourav, I will try to follow your instructions, but 1st, I use Azure Devops Server on*-prem and my build machine is a windows 10 whaich has Node 18 and NPM 9, would that be of impact on the outcome?

Comment: u try these steps and let me know if any blockers, I will try to customise the above steps according to your infra. However, I don't think it will be an issue.

Comment: Sorav, I did update pipeline with "Use node 10" and npm commands using cmd, created app service for windows and linux with Node 18 as the stack but it did not help. When I deployed to a linux app service, I get a page indicating that there was no contents to display, but the win app service always the same error.

Comment: Can u share the link to the entire repo to exactly to identify the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Which repo you mean? The repo after deployment to Azure or the repo on my on-prem Azure devops server?

Comment: Sourav, I managed to add a fedora linux build agent and now build pipeline uses this agent not the win agent, however, it fails with the following error                              : npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/salam/projects/myagent/_work/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/salam/projects/myagent/_work/package.json'   not sure why it looks for package directory in _work and not in _work\1\s where there is the source code along with package.json

Comment: Sorry for the answer I posted 5 minutes ago, in fact I missed the "npm run start" on Stage 1, I added it6 and now when I browse I get                                                     :( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources. in the log stream I have                                                                                                                          

2023-02-04T17:53:46.928889585Z: [INFO]  A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2023-02-04T17:53:46.928893386Z: [INFO]

Comment: I will post a 2nd answer to put the full log stream output

Answer (score 0):

Sourav, I managed to add a fedora linux build agent and now build pipeline uses this agent followed exactly same steps you indicates, build pipeline runs on a linux machine, add aapp service plan with 18 TLS and linux as the platform, ran build then the release in my azure devops server which were successful, now I am getting this when I browse the website. QUESTION : Should I declare a PORT env variable in order to be able to access or should it work without it?

[image]